# Не срабатывает событие click второй раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не срабатывает второй раз событие по нажатию на активный элемент. В чем может быть причина, подскажите, пожалуйста?

```js
$('.products-grid-header li.active-items').on('click', function() {
    $('.products-grid-header-item').show();

    $('.products-grid-header-item').click(function() {
        $('.products-grid-header li.active-items').removeClass('active-items');
        $(this).addClass('active-items');
        $('.products-grid-header li:not(.active-items)').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });        
});
```

```css
.products-grid-header li:not(.active-items){
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid-header">
    <li class="products-grid-header-item active-items">
        <a class="" href="#1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="products-grid-header-item">
        <a class="" href="#2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="products-grid-header-item">
        <a class="" href="#3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="products-grid-header-item">
        <a class="" href="#4">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="products-grid-header-item">
        <a class="" href="#5">5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="products-grid-header-item">
        <a class="" href="#6">6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а зачем в клике еще 1 кли можеть его вынести отдельно

Comment: По первому клику открывается меню, второй клик выбранному элементу присвоит класс active-items, а остальные скроет (display:none).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клик срабатывает, но второй обработчик сразу же прячет элементы. Рассмотри такой вариант

```js
$('.products-grid-header-item').on('click', function() {
  $('.products-grid-header-item').toggle();
  $(this).show()
})
```

```css
.products-grid-header li:not(.active-items) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid-header">
  <li class="products-grid-header-item active-items">
    <a class="" href="#1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#4">4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#5">5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="products-grid-header-item">
    <a class="" href="#6">6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Какое простое решение) спасибо большое, все работает как надо!

Comment: а как можно сделать, чтобы меню выпадало более плавно? Добавляю в toggle('slow') и пропадает первый элемент, если добавить то же свойство в show() то первый элемент сначала плавно пропадает, а потом плавно появлется, с опозданием. Переделала немного функцию, чтоб добавлялся нужный класс для стилей: $('.products-grid-header-item').on('click', function() {
        $('.products-grid-header-item').toggle();
        $('.products-grid-header li.active-items').removeClass('active-items');
        $(this).show();
        $(this).addClass('active-items');
    });